# Как в webpack 5 исключить удаление некоторых файлов?

Tags: webpack, webpack5

Коллеги, в webpack_5 использую плагин `clean-webpack-plugin`, все прекрасно работает.

Но тут пришлось реализовать такую штуку, исключить удаления двух файлов. Мне надо исключить файлы

```
.git && README.md
```

Прочел  оф. доку.

[npm - clean-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-webpack-plugin)

[github - clean-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin)

Вроде это то, что надо    ***`{cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns : ['.git', 'README.md']}`***

Но это не работает.

Где-то нашел свойство `exclude: []`

но на оф. сайте про такое не нашел ни какой информации.  Подскажите как исключить удаление
этих файлов `.git && README.md`?

Comment: А как так вообще получлилось, что в выходной папке присутствуют эти два файла? Обычно выходная папка подразумевается быть полностью пустой...

Comment: Это просто к меня идея **фикс**.... )))